# unble to store data in store using context hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to store the selected items in array and store. I could able to store selected items in an array perfectly but there is a delay happening while storing them in store. for example, I selected three items if when I console array I am getting 3 items but in-store console its showing two items.

This is my code

```
const checkSelection = useCallback(
        (developer, e) => {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                setCheckedItems([...checkedItems, developer]);
            } else {
                setCheckedItems((prevState) => prevState.filter((item) => item !== developer));
            }

// these is my store data
            saveSelectedDeveloper({
                selectedItems: checkedItems,
            });
        },
        [saveSelectedDeveloper, checkedItems],
    );
```

I am pretty new to this context concept can someone tell me where is the mistake in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happends coz checkedItems didn't update immediately, it's update only next render, so you should set same value as you set in ur setCheckedItems

```
if (e.target.checked) {
                setCheckedItems([...checkedItems, developer]);
                saveSelectedDeveloper({
                  selectedItems: [...checkedItems, developer],
                });
            } else {
                setCheckedItems((prevState) => {
                  saveSelectedDeveloper({
                    selectedItems: prevState.filter((item) => item !== developer),
                  });  
                  return prevState.filter((item) => item !== developer)
                });
            }
```